# Get all atributes names of an object

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Let's say I have a class which looks like this :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public var attribute1;
    public var attribute2;
}
```

and I'd like to get attribute1 and attribute2 as strings. I tried this :

```
var test:MyClass = new MyClass();

for (var key:String in test)  
{
    trace(test[key]); 
}
```

but it does not work, it never goes in the loop. How can I do what I want to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A for..in loop enumerates only dynamically added properties. Declared variables and methods of classes are not enumerated in for..in loops. This means that most classes in the ActionScript API will not display any properties in a for..in loop.

For a solution read:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_8.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use AS reflection/introspection.
The native way is using describeType function, like this:

```
public function getDetails():void { 
        var classInfo:XML = describeType(button1);

        // List the class name.
        ta1.text = "Class " + classInfo.@name.toString() + "\n";

        // List the object's variables, their values, and their types.
        for each (var v:XML in classInfo..variable) {
            ta1.text += "Variable " + v.@name + "=" + button1[v.@name] + 
                " (" + v.@type + ")\n";
        }
    }
```

(from flex doc: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_8.html)

I'm not sure but I think the class mx.utils.ObjectUtil can make it simpler. And it's still native way.

Another option is using a library to make it easier.
Look this one: http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-reflect/introduction.html